# how to configure a manifest file

Tags: html, manifest, offline-caching

This is my first time in stackoverflow so if i break any rule or something, please tell me and ill try to fix it asap.

Im trying to configure a manifest (appcache) file to download 2 files( one html and one JS) and be able to use that HTML in offline mode, but after many trys, i couldnt configure the manifest file (or maybe is something else fail?) to store the appcache files.

At the moment i have in the same folder, 3 files: juego.html , damas.appcache and juego.js

damas.appcache:

```
CACHE MANIFEST
CACHE:
juego.html
juego.js
NETWORK:
*
```

and in the html file...
juego.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html manifest="damas.appcache">
...
```

I dont think that more HTML code or the javascript code is needed for my explanation but if needed, ill put it.

¿How can i got the files to be stored in local?

Thanks to all

Answer (score 2):

It's possible that you have an older version of the html cached. This seems to be the case because your setup looks correct, but you are missing a unique value—such as a timestamp—in your `damas.appcache`. The cache manifest only gets updated when there is a change to that file.

It's also possible that your mime-type is incorrect. Ensure that the mime-type set for the cache manifest is set to `text/cache-manifest`.

**Apache**:
`AddType text/cache-manifest .appcache`

---

### References:

See Cache manifest on my website: http://pygeek.com

See *A Beginner's Guide to Using the Application Cache*: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/appcache/beginner/

Comment: i've add this line under CACHE MANIFEST according to your explanation

#version 1.2 22-04-2015

but it doesnt seems to work still

Comment: @AdrianGonzalez I've updated the answer to reflect a second possible issue that you may be encountering.

Comment: sorry for the delay, i was really bussy today

I really dont know how to know that....

The way i saw it ( dunno if its correct) was to go to http://pygeek.com/manifest.appcache
and there with chrome-> inspect ->network , it says type: text/cache-manifest

in my case i tried in 2 places, first of all with MAMP (apache app for MAC) and it said me that it was a plain text file, and the second one with xammp in a windows, and it told me that was text/manifest file

But it really was the same  file, i just copy&paste it ... so i dunno...

any help/tip for that?

Comment: @AdrianGonzalez You have to modify your apache config file. I'll update my answer with that info.

Comment: I made some changes to get the file as appcache, one was what u said, the other one was to add a line into  mime.types, and  after all that changes ( and a update into damas.appcache) now it sais that is a text/cache-manifest file, but still doesnt save nothing to work offline..

any other suggestion? and BTW THANKS for your time

Comment: im working in local, but ill upload it somewhere ...so u can see it ( but ill have to do it on monday, i dont have any time right now)